# Object leak after adding a subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, memory-leaks

Fellow developers,

I'm trying to set a web image as a background for a UIButton. Everything works execept when I build and analyze it shows that aImage still has a +1 reference. Adding a release for aImage after addSubview doesn't solve it. I think I might solve it by subclassing and writing a custom dealloc but that feels like a convoluted solution. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks !

```
UIImage *aImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mUrl]];
[myOverviewButton setBackgroundImage:aImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aView addSubview:myOverviewButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either add an autorelease to the aImage, or call release on it manually.

```
UIImage *aImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mUrl]] autorelease];
```

When you call setBackgroundImage:, the button is performing a retain on the image.  When you did the alloc/init you did a retain that was never released.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the code you've shown finishes executing, `aImage` should have a reference count of 2: one from the `alloc` call and one from the `setBackgroundImage:forState:` call. You should release after `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to balance the `alloc`, but you will still have a reference count of 1. This is expected -- otherwise `myOverviewButton` wouldn't have an image to work with. It should go down to 0 when `myOverviewButton` deallocates.